# Temperature sensor bugs

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, debugging, debug

My project is based on a moving fan using DHT11 sensors. I have used 2 void loops and the IDE is showing an error

> "exit status 1
>   redefinition of 'void loop()'"

One doubt: Can we use 2 void loops in the code? Please see and identify the errors.

2nd doubt: `dht DHT;` shows error

> "exit status 1
>   'dht' does not name a type" for my version of Arduino 1.8.1

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

 // Including library for dht
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
#define dht_dpin 12
dht DHT;
#define pwm 9

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(" Fan Speed");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(" Controlling");
  delay(2000);
  analogWrite(pwm, 255);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Circuit Digest ");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  DHT.read11(dht_dpin);
  int temp=DHT.temperature;
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Temperature:");
  lcd.print(temp);   // Printing temperature on LCD
  lcd.print("oC");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  if(temp <26 ) {
    analogWrite(9,0);
    lcd.print("Fan OFF");
    delay(100);
  } else if(temp==26) {
    analogWrite(pwm, 51);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 20%");
    delay(100);
  } else if(temp==27) {
    analogWrite(pwm, 102);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 40%");
    delay(100);
  } else if(temp==28) {
    analogWrite(pwm, 153);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 60%");
    delay(100);
  } else if(temp==29) {
    analogWrite(pwm, 204);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 80%");
    delay(100);
  } else if(temp>29) {
    analogWrite(pwm, 255);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 100%");
    delay(100);
  }
  delay(3000);
}
}
```

Comment: There can be only one loop() function, and you have two.

Comment: Two void loops are not allowed, why do you need one??

Comment: After I remove the 2nd loop,then also there is an error.

Comment: send me the code after removing the loop, and also be specific  about what you are trying to do.

Comment: “_dht DHT;_”: You mean `DHT dht;`. The syntax is `type_name variable_name;` and the type name is `DHT` (upper case).

Answer (score 1):

Here, below is updated version of your code.

Before running this code, you have to download DHT library. Just click on `Click Here` and you find good explanation & library of DHT11 Sensor. Becuase this library I usually preferred for my code. So, please download it and then run my code.

[Click Here](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/DHT11-Humidity-TempSensor)

And two void() loop never used. Put your all logic in one void() loop.

Note: This is not tested code. So if you face any problem then update me.

```
#include <dht.h>                // DHT library
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>       // LCD library

LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 12

#define pwm 9

float temp;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(pwm, OUTPUT); //Pin as OUTPUT
}

void loop()
{

 int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
 temp = DHT.temperature;
 Serial.print("Temperature = ");
 Serial.print("\t");
 Serial.print(temp);
 delay(1000);

 lcd.begin(16, 2);
 lcd.clear();
 lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
 lcd.print("Fan Speed");
 lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
 lcd.print("Controlling");
 delay(2000);
 lcd.clear();
 lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
 lcd.print("Circuit Digest");
 delay(2000);
 lcd.clear();
 lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
 lcd.print("Temperature:");
 lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
 lcd.print(temp);

 lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

 if(temp < 26 )
 { 
    analogWrite(pwm, 0);
    lcd.print("Fan OFF");
    delay(100);
 }
 else if(temp == 26)
 {
    analogWrite(pwm, 51);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 20%");
    delay(100);
 }
 else if(temp == 27)
 {
    analogWrite(pwm, 102);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 40%");
    delay(100);
 }
 else if(temp == 28)
 {
    analogWrite(pwm, 153);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 60%");
    delay(100);
 }
 else if(temp == 29)
 {
    analogWrite(pwm, 204);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 80%");
    delay(100);
 }
 else if(temp > 29)
 {
    analogWrite(pwm, 255);
    lcd.print("Fan Speed: 100%");
    delay(100);
  }  
}
```